# Focus is changed when inspecting element with CTRL+SHIFT+C

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I want to inspect an element in the browser with either CTRL-SHIFT-C or by clicking [image: arrow], the current focus is changed, possibly leading to elements that was previously visible not being visible any longer.

Is there some way of avoiding that?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the element you need focus on in the Elements panel. Then find the `:hov` toggle (As of V49 iirc, 48 may still be a thumb-pin icon) which will open a menu for toggling given element states. From there, just select the one you need applied (focus in this case.) That will force the given state even if focus is somewhere else.

[image: force pseudo state]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however, the element has already dissapeared by now, I can of course find it again, if it is still in the DOM, but I do not want the element to dissapear in the first place.

Comment: There is no way to avoid that bit. Opening DevTools causes a focus change on the page (since focus goes to DevTools.) This is an effect of how DevTools works within the page context. You need to force the state against what is needed after opening DevTools.